# Unit scale in libgdx tile maps

Tags: java, libgdx

I'm pretty confused about the implementation of unit scales in libgdx tile maps. For example if I specify my unit scale to be 1/16f and have an actor move from (0,0) to (0,1) in my logical world, will the sprite actually move 16 pixels? And does this mean an actor can only be directly on a tile?

Comment: With "tile maps" you mean maps rendered with the `TiledRenderer` and imported from .tmx files? If so, i can't tell you much, as i never used `Tiled`. But i also used tile based maps, and i made them by using a custom `Viewport` for the `camera`. For me every tile was 1 unit big, and the visible part of the map was (for example) 80 units wide and 45 units heigh. It was also possible to move the character by 0.2 (or whatever) units. How many pixels the `Sprite` would move on the `Screen` depends on the size/resolution, as i have devided the screen in 80 units and so pixels/unit is dynamic.

Comment: So when I render my sprite with my spritebatch would I draw it at `getX() * (1/unit scale)`

Comment: Shouldn't it be `getX()*unitScale`?

Comment: If my unit scale is 1/16 and I try to draw a sprite at 1,1 and I had `getX() * unit scale` it would try to draw the sprite at 1/16, 1/16 right? But I actually want it at 16,16

Comment: Ah okay if the `unit scale` is units/pixel yes. I thought it is pixels/unit. Then you are right. But i would use a custom `Viewport` for the `camera` or the `stage`, so that you can draw them 1 on 1, meaning if you draw on `getX()`, `getY()` you get the desired result. At least i suggest to do that.

Comment: No problem. Did it solve your problem? Does now everything work like you wanted?

Comment: Well actually I do need help setting up my ortho cam to work with my map

Comment: There are lots of questions and answer to this here on SO and also lots of tutorials out there :P

Answer (score 0):

If you choose 1/16f as unit scale for your map, all your coordinates in the map will be tile-based (so to speak) instead of pixel-based.

You can achieve this with Sprites, for example, by scaling the Sprite by (1/16f) also. Now all coordinates (and the size of the sprite) is scaled to fit the tile map.

Remember to set the correct projection for your batch-renderer before you do batch-drawing, so that the coordinates are converted correctly. Otherwise you will have to figure out where the camera is and adjust your drawing manually.
`batch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined)` should work.